# How do I automatically create burned-in subtitles in Premiere Pro?

Tags: video-editor, premiere, subtitles

I have subtitles for a video in .srt format and I want to use this create 'burned-in' subtitles in Adobe Premiere Pro. Is this possible to do - and how?

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: related question: http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/5160/render-srt-subtitles-to-video

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by burned in?  Do you mean you wish to actually render the text on to the video or that you wish to encode it in a format that supports inclusion of a subtitle channel?  For actually making them a permanent part of the video, I've always done it through titles rather than an srt.  I unfortunately don't have any experience with the latter option of making them a subtitle channel in a compatible format, but it would likely depend greatly on the format chosen.

Comment: By 'burning' in I meant rendering them as a text titles within the video. I know I can use the title feature to add titles manually, but some form of converting SRTs to text tiles according to timing would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with Premiere without plugins and I don't know of any that would do this.
I recommend doing this outside of premiere like explained in this question: [Render srt subtitles to video?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/5160/render-srt-subtitles-to-video)

Answer (score 0):

### Official Documentation

> Premiere Pro lets you burn in permanent captions into your video.
>   Burned-in captions are always visible regardless of whether closed
>   captioning is enabled on your television or streaming device or not.
>
> Premiere Pro supports burning in both closed captions and open
>   captions while exporting your video.
>
> When you import SRT files and XML files that  have open caption data
>   in them, Premiere Pro automatically converts these files to CEA-708
>   CC1 closed caption files. You can then edit these files and burn in
>   the captions as subtitles while exporting using Premiere Pro or Adobe
>   Media Encoder.
>
> In the Export Settings dialog box, select the Export Format as Burn
>   Captions Into Video.
>
> Note: You cannot edit captions that are burned into the video.

https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/working-with-captions.html

Answer (score 0):

Use aegisub to create an srt file (believe me it is easier this way). Then simply import the srt file into premiere. It will create a title sequence that will act as a layer that you can render onto the video. There are of course other ways of doing this such as what Ryan posted.

I personally do not like Premiere's handling of subtitles as there is no way to batch format all the subs!