# Is it possible to store subtitle srt files in an m3u playlist file?

Tags: video, file-formats, subtitles, playlist

I have a folder that contains around 51 videos and another folder with their respective subtitles.

I don't want to merge the folders into one folder so I was wondering if there's a way to store subtitle `srt` files location (or at least a folder location for all subtitles) in an `m3u` playlist file along with the video files locations.

**Note:** Video file format is `flv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m3u` playlists only contains links to the media itself that you're playing.

It doesn't actually consider the `srt` file at all. If the software used to play back the `m3u` file support `srt` files it will look in the same folder for the same file as the video only with the extension switched to `srt`.

You will therefor always need to store the `srt` together with the video file.

Comment: So if i'm using `VLC media player` there's no way that I can change the preferences of the software to change the behavior of looking for subtitle files in a specific folder, or to burn the `srt` file into the `flv` video file.

Comment: @YahyaKACEM Burning an `srt` in a `flv` video is content for another question. This question is already asked [here](http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/5160/render-srt-subtitles-to-video/5161#5161)

Answer (score 2):

yes, VLC supports that with the `EXTVLCOPT` custom tag.

example:

```
#EXTINF:-1,Abenobashi ED - Anata No Kokoro Ni (In Your Heart)
#EXTVLCOPT:sub-file=/p/Documents/mus/lyrics/Abenobashi ED - Anata No Kokoro Ni (In Your Heart).srt
#EXTVLCOPT:subsdec-encoding=UTF-8
Abenobashi ED - Anata No Kokoro Ni (In Your Heart).flv
```

Note that the path must be absolute and remote files are (unfortunataly) unsupported.

Alternatively you may change the `sub-autodetect-path` in `vlcrc` and add more search paths.